# Goland ssh debug mode fail: executable doesn't containt debug information

Tags: go, debugging, ide, goland

I use Goland ssh to write code. I fail to use debug mode in my project, the breakpoints turn into gray crossed circles and report error "executable doesn't containt debug information".
[The error information is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN3Pz.jpg)

[This is the Run/Debug Configuration of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZy6W.png)

However, I still could use debug mode and set normal breakpoints in Testing file.

Comment: Did anyone meet the same problem? Please give me some hints to solve it!!! Thx!!

Comment: When I add breakpoints for the first time, this error message is shown in terminal. "error layer=debugger error loading binary "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0": could not parse .eh_frame section: pointer encoding not supported 0x9b at 0x12e8"

Comment: How do you start your application?

Answer (score 2):

I met exactly the same problem just now.

Finally I find the reason is the function which I set breakpoint doesn't been called in the repo.

It's called by another repo, so compile and debug the repo that call this function can solve this problem.

The error "error layer=debugger error loading binary "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0": could not parse .eh_frame section: pointer encoding not supported 0x9b at 0x12e8" still exists, but the breakpoints won't turn into gray crossed circles.

Answer (score 0):

please see this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-13005  .
Next 2022.2 nightly build bundles delve which doesn't produce an error.